# F(x) is a function differentiable and monotonic strictly increasing on the OPEN interval (a,b).

Tags: derivatives

> $f(x)$ is a  differentiable and  strictly increasing function on the open interval $(a,b)$.
>
> Prove or disprove that $f'(c)>0\; \forall c\;\in (a,b)$.

I was trying to apply Lagrange's derivative theorem, but the condition that the function must be continuous on the closed interval $[a,b]$ is not given. Im assuming the answer should be false, but I can't prove it's false or give a counterexample. Can we find a way to apply Lagrange's theorem? Then for sure, it's a true affirmative.

Comment: Try $x^3$ .... you can figure out an interval.

Comment: $F(x)=x^3$ on the interval $(-1,1)$ is strictly increasing but $F'(0)=0$

Answer (score 0):

$f:x\to x^3$ on $(-1,1)$ is a counter-example for your statement, as $f'(0)=3\times(0)^2=0$  .

The true implication is that if $f$ is differentiable on an open interval $(a,b)$ and strictly increasing, then $f'\geq0$ and there exists no open interval $(x,y)\subset(a,b)$ such that $\forall{t}\in(x,y) : f'(t)=0$, which means that $f'$ is never constant at zero on an open interval of $(a,b)$, since if it was the case, we'd get that $f$ is constant on that interval  which would contradict the strict monotony.

In fact, suppose by contradiction that there exists $(x,y)\subset(a,b)$ on which $f$ is always zero, then let $t,h\in(x,y)$ such that $t\neq h$. By the mean value theorem, there exists $c\in(x,y)$ such that :
\begin{equation}
f'(c)=\frac{f(t)-f(h)}{t-h}
\end{equation}
Since $f$ is always zero on $(x,y)$, so in particular $f'(c)=0$, hence $f(t)=f(h)$ which contradicts the strict monotony of $f$.